# Show that there exists values of $x$ whose first digit is not $1$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x$ be a positive integer. Show that if $x, x^2, x^3, \dots, x^n$ all start with the same digit, and $n$ is a positive integer, there exist values of $x$ whose first digit is not $1$.

I presume we are working in base $10$ for this question. I am wondering how to get the first digit out of the powers of $x$ since we will need to know the greatest power of ten dividing each power of $x$.

Comment: What does "there exists values of $x$ whose first digit is not $1$" mean?  $2$ doesn't begin with $1$....does that prove your claim?

Comment: @lulu No, it's not false. It says "there exists."

Comment: Then I don't understand the question.  Of course there exist values of $x$ whose first digit is not $1$.

Comment: @lulu They mean "show that there exists values of $x$ **that satisfy the given conditions**".

Comment: @lulu - The question asks for a way to prove that there are solutions which do NOT start with 1 beginning from the two statements above

Comment: @K.Hoffmann  But...starting with $x=1$ I can take any $n$ I like so the first clause appears to be trivially satisfied for all $n$.  Are you saying the problem ought to read "show that for all $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists some $m\in \mathbb N$ such that the first digit of $m$ is not $1$ and such that $\{m,m^2,\cdots, m^n\}$ all begin with the same digit."?

Comment: @lulu I guess i would state the Question the way you just did - we are looking for solutions on $x$ so that $\{x,x^2,\cdot \cdot \cdot ,x^n \}$ statisfy that their first digit is the same. So if we have $x$ being represented in their base 10 form $x=\sum_{k=0}^{m}{10^k \cdot a_k}$ with $a_k$ being the digits we want that all highest $a_m$ are equal. And since we have $a_m \neq 1$ we dont look for answers like $x=1$ or $x=10$ even tho they trivially exist. We just want to show that there are more solutions then those.

Comment: @K.Hoffmann  Fair enough...at least that is a well posed question.  But of course if we take $x=10^N-1$ for very large $N$ then many powers of $x$ will begin with $9$.

Comment: @lulu The question is well-posed, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Look at powers of $99$. $99^n$ for any positive integer $1 \leq n \leq 10$ has a first digit of $9$.

Look at powers of $999$. $999^n$ for any positive integer $1 \leq n \leq 105$ has a first digit of $9$.

Now, if you're given a value of $n$, what kind of values of $x$ would you look for to satisfy the given conditions?

---

Here's another way to think of it:
$$.99^k > .9 \ \text{for all} \ 1 \leq k \leq 10$$
$$.999^k > .9 \ \text{for all} \ 1 \leq k \leq 105$$

You want to find the following for some $n$: 
$$y^k > .9 \ \text{for all} \ 1 \leq k \leq n$$

If you substitute $n$ into that inequality, you get $y^n > .9$. How can you solve that inequality for $y$ and once you do, how can you convert the decimal $y$ back to a suitable integer $x$?

Comment: The other hint I would give is to apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: @NobleMushtak How do you determine the range of $n$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 For any $n$, you can always find a positive integer $x$ such that $x, x^2, x^3, ..., x^n$ all begin with the digit $9$. I've added another hint above that might help you.

Comment: @NobleMushtak We get $y > 10^{\frac{\log(0.9)}{n}}$ right?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Yes, that's right. Now, if you choose $10^{\frac{\log 0.9}{n}} < y < 1$, you need to convert that to an integer $x$ by multiplying $y$ by a power of $10$ and then rounding to the nearest integer so that the first digit is $9$ (i.e. make sure it does not round up to $10$). We know that such an integer exists because $0.9 < y < 1$, so the first digit in $y$ is $9$, but if we multiply by $10$ enough, there should be some non-$9$ digit so that we can round to the nearest integer without rounding to the next power of $10$.